# Insert tag after certain number of words in a long paragaragh

Tags: jquery, string

I have a very long text(user inputted through editors) which I want to paginate. For that I was planning to use one of the jQuery based pagination plugin,
but all of those plugins requires group of elements which they split into pagination eg. some plugin may require the element to be in an `<ul><li></li>....</ul>` pattern.

How can I insert the specific element after certain number of words in paragraph repeatedly, using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,.";
modifiedString = string.replace(/(.{10})/g,"$1<br>");
```

This will replace every 10th character with `<br>` tag.